# how to save click counts from multiple links ,on a dynamic table to a database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i have a dynamic table that has a list of records, basically for all rows of the table there is a link to click, that passes the id of that row clicked to the next page,
my question is how can i save and display the number of times each link have been clicked ?

here is my code

```
<table width="100%" >
    <tr bgcolor="#FF3399" style="color:#FFF">

      <td><h3><strong>Topic</strong></h3></td>
      <td><h3>Author</h3></td>

      <td><h3>Date</h3></td>
      <td><strong>Replies</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Views</strong></td>
      </tr>
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr bgcolor="#009900" style="color:#FFF">

        <td><h4><a style="color:#FFF" onclick="spinn();"  data-ajax="false" href="send.php?id=<?php echo $row_forum['id']; ?>"><strong><?php echo $row_forum['Topic']; ?></strong></a></h4></td>
        <td bgcolor="#009900"><h4><?php echo $row_forum['Author']; ?></h4></td>

        <td><h4><?php echo date("g : i a, j/F/Y,",strtotime($row_forum['Date'])); ?></h4></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $row_forum['Replies']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_forum['Views']; ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_forum = mysql_fetch_assoc($forum)); ?>
  </table>
```

Comment: You can do that on the next page you're opening, since you have the id of the link you have clicked

Comment: how do i go about that please

Comment: You can get the id in the next page from the QueryString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page that is the target of your link, simply invoke a method which will increase your `count` field in the database. You can put code like this in your target page:

```
<?php
    function increaseCount() {
        // ... connect to db
        mysql_query('UPDATE table SET count=count+1 WHERE id='.$id);
    }

    increaseCount($_GET['id']);
?>
```

Please note, that the above code is **very trivial and dangerous** and only shows the concept. It does not protect you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) **at all**. Doesn't even check, if the `id` parameter in the address exists.
Also, don't use methods like `mysql_query` - they're depracated.

Alternatively, try using Ajax to change the behavior of link's click event - send an ajax request to PHP script which will increment your `count` field in the database, and then follow your link's `href` :)

1. [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest)
2. [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

## Edit

```
$topicId = $_GET['id']; // you need to change 'id' to the name of your ID-parameter in the URL
$viewsIncrementQuery = "UPDATE `topic` SET `Views` = `Views` + 1 WHERE `id` = " . $topicID;
$incremented = mysql_query($viewsIncrementQuery, $epl) or die(mysql_error());
```

You need to put that code somewhere close to where you extract data from the database, so probably after the `$query_lin = sprintf( (...)` part.

If it throws an error - show it's message.

Comment: i have done that, and this is what i did, mysql_select_db($database_epl, $epl);
$query_lin = sprintf("SELECT * FROM topic WHERE id = %s ORDER BY `Date` DESC", GetSQLValueString($colname_lin, "int"));
$topicId = $_GET['id']; // you need to change 'id' to the name of your ID-parameter in the URL
$viewsIncrementQuery = "UPDATE `topic` SET `Views` = `Views` + 1 WHERE `id` = " . $topicID;
$incremented = mysql_query($viewsIncrementQuery, $epl) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: but i get this error Notice: Undefined variable: topicID in C:\xampp\htdocs\mobileepl\send.php on line 347
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: The notice `Undefined variable: topicID` tells you exactly what you need to know. Now check the code I gave you **carefully** and correct the typo. And go read something about PHP bacics, because...man, you gotta think by yourself a little. No more help from me. I can't believe the code you posted was developed by you. No way.

Comment: it was, only that by dreamweaver

Comment: Don't do that (generate code automatically), at least not at the beginning. I wouldn't start doing this until the moment when you can actually understand what this code is doing. Also, those functions, which DreamWeaver used for you, are going to be removed from PHP in the future versions, so your code will not work anymore (unless you use older, slower and less secure versions of PHP).